# How to draw text using loadStrings(); and text();?

Tags: string, text, processing

basic loadstrings() code:

```
String[] txt = loadStrings("/Users/rjth/Desktop/data.txt");
println("there are " + txt.length + " lines");
println(txt);
```

when I add text(); or RG.getText(); I am given an error code:

```
String[] txt = loadStrings("/Users/rjth/Desktop/data.txt");
println("there are " + txt.length + " lines");
println(txt);
text(txt, 1, 1);
```

*error: The method text(char[], int, int float, float) in the type PApplet is not applicable for the arguments (String[], int, int)*

where is the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

well that's because txt as you set it is an array (that's what loadstrings gives out).. You have to iterate over it and set the text to each one of its elements like this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < txt.length; i++) text(txt[i],1,1);
```

or:

```
for(String s: txt) text(s,1,1);
```

Comment: might want to increment the y position along with the counter to avoid overlaps, or accumulate/concatenate all the lines into a string then make a single call to text()` to render it. Also, if the next line separator is known (which I'm guessing will be `\n` if the text was generated on osx or '\r\n' on windows) then [join()](http://processing.org/reference/join_.html) the loadStrings() result by that new line separator into a single string. +1 for also showing the for(Element e : collection) loop :)